# Find and replace operation

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace

I am trying to use PHP to find and replace from a given string. I suppose this is similar to what you might do in a text editor (regex, or similar).

This is an example initial string:

```
[quote=Registered_User;0123456]This is a message.[/quote]
```

The desired output:

```
[quote=Registered_User pid=0123456]This is a message.[/quote]
```

I have experimented using preg_replace(), but the issue arises when I want to retain the number element.

I cannot use str_replace() to replace ';' with ' pid=' because there may be instances in the initial string where an isolated semi-colon is found.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

We can find an instance where a word, semicolon, and a number come after `quote=` and then replace it with the new format:

```
preg_replace("/quote=(\w+);(\d+)/", "quote=$1 pid=$2", $string);
```

Comment: There was a mistake in there.  fixed

Answer (score 0):

If the start of the string "Registered_User;0123456]This is a message" does not change you could something like the following.

```
$string = "[quote=Registered_User;0123456]This is a message.[/quote]";
$beginStr = "[quote=Registered_User pid=";
$string = $beginStr . substr($string,23);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will find a semicolon preceded by 15 word characters, preceded by "quote=", and change that semicolon into " pid=", however this will only work if the word (Registered_User) is 15 characters.

```
preg_replace("/(?<=([quote=]{6}(\w{15})));/", " pid=", $string);
```